# Not getting networking metrics from scollector on Centos 7.1

Tags: bosun, scollector

We have bosun running on Centos 6.4 and many nodes on that OS also. We added some Centos 7.1 nodes and while we get basic metrics like os.cpu, no network-related metrics appear.

I recompiled the latest scollector on 7.1 and pushed that out, but it didn't help. Do I need to recompile the bosun on 6.4 also, or is all backwards compatible?

Thanks
Ken

Comment: This is not really a programming question. It would be more appropriate on [sf].

Answer (score 0):

Right now the interfaces it will collect from is restricted to a regular expression:

https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/master/cmd/scollector/collectors/ifstat_linux.go

```
var ifstatRE = regexp.MustCompile(`\s+(eth\d+|em\d+_\d+/\d+|em\d+_\d+|em\d+|` +
`bond\d+|team\d+|` + `p\d+p\d+_\d+/\d+|p\d+p\d+_\d+|p\d+p\d+):(.*)`)
```

The problem is due to aggregation we need to be clear if an interface is a physical interface, a tunnel, a team/bond etc. So we don't want to accidently get virtual interfaces in os.net.bytes as it messes up aggregation.

There are a couple [PRs](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aopen%20ifstat), but they need to address the categorization issue and not have yet. So the immediate workarounds are you can edit the code to have what you need, work on a pr to make that configurable with category, or rename your interfaces.